# Como dividir corretamente um número até somente um digito em C?

Tags: c, funções

Eu tenho a seguinte função :

```
divisibilidade11(int num);
```

E as seguintes variáveis :

```
int dividendo;
int divisor;
```

Quando o usuário entrar com o digito `11` para a variável `divisor` a função `divisibilidade11` será chamada e irá verificar se a variável `dividendo` é divisível pelo `divisor`. E para verificar se é ou não divisível, terá que seguir os critérios : **Caso a soma deste algarismo de ordem par (Sp) subtraído da soma de ordem impar (Si), resultar em 0 ou em um número divisível por 11, ele retorna `true` e caso não, ele retorna `false`.**

**Exemplo :**

> O usuário entra com o número `2376` para a variável `dividendo`;
>
> O usuário entra com o número `11` para a variável `divisor`;
>
> É chamada a função `divisibilidade11`, para verificar se é ou não divisível;
>
> É feita a soma dos impares (Si) = 3+6 = 9;
>
> É feita a soma dos pares (Sp) = 2+7 = 9;
>
> Si - Sp = 0; Logo, portanto, 2376 é divisível por 11.
>
> OBS : O algarismo mais a direita é o primeiro de ordem impar.

**Exemplo de como apareceria para o usuário :**

[image]

A função `divisibilidade11` tem que repetir o processo até que o resultado seja um número com um digito. Se este digito for igual a 0, então o número original é divisível por 11.

Comment: Do exercício não. Por que ele conta o algarismo mais a direita como primeiro de ordem impar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, percebi após realizar uma releitura da sua pergunta o que você quis dizer. Por favor, veja minha resposta, e tire suas dúvidas se necessário.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer aqui seguindo os critérios de divisibilidade, se eu conseguir eu posto o código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Utilizando Strings

Sabendo que o valor máximo para inteiros que a maioria dos computadores suporta nos dias atuais é de até 19 dígitos, utilizarei uma string de 20 dígitos para realizar esta operação.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>    

char divisibilidade11(long long int dividendo){
    char array_numerico[20] = "";
    int total_par = 0;
    int total_impar = 0;
    snprintf(array_numerico, 20, "%lld", dividendo);
    for(char iterador = strlen(array_numerico) - 1, par = 0; iterador >= 0; iterador -= 1){
        if(!par){
            total_impar += array_numerico[iterador] - 48;
            par = 1;
        }
        else{
            total_par += array_numerico[iterador] - 48;
            par = 0;
        }
    }
    if((total_par - total_impar) == 0 || ((total_par - total_impar) % 11 == 0)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

## Utilizando Operações Matemáticas Decimais

```
char divisibilidade11(long long int dividendo){
    int total_par = 0;
    int total_impar = 0;
    char par = 0;
    while(dividendo != 0){
        if(!par){
            total_impar += (dividendo % 10);
            par = 1;
        }
        else{
            total_par += (dividendo % 10);
            par = 0;
        }
        dividendo /= 10;
    }
    if((total_par - total_impar) == 0 || (total_par - total_impar) % 11 == 0)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas o problema é que não posso usar array. Por isto, este exercício é complicado de fazer.

Comment: Sem problemas! Façamos de uma outra maneira, então! @Mondial, minha segunda resposta cumpre com os requisitos da sua questão?

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado por ter paciência para ter modificado a resposta. Vou testar aqui segundo os critérios do exercício.

Comment: Sem problemas! Essa questão foi não só um aprendizado de C como também uma maneira interessante de relembrar certas regras básicas dos sistemas de representação numéricos matemáticos, e também serviu como uma comparação entre as duas principais formas de se resolver a questão. Note que a segunda forma pode, para muitos, requerer mais pensamento, mas ela realmente é muito mais eficiente e rápida do que a primeira, que requer o uso de várias funções extras que a tornam muito mais pesada e ineficiente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela paciência em responder a minha pergunta e modificar a sua resposta quando necessário. Mas o problema que ocorreu é de que neste exemplo em que você mostrou, você colocar par = 1 caso o algarismo der em par, ou par = 0 caso o algarismo der em impar e depois subtrair , acaba em fazer com que alguns números mesmo não sendo divididos por 11, sejam mostrados que são. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado por tudo, dei +1. Eu terei que fazer de outra forma, mas mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: Terei que fazer que nem o que eu coloquei no exemplo no post, em que eu tenho que separar o número em algarismos separados, e depois pegar o par com par e somar, e impar com impar. Por exemplo, o número 1771561, em que a Soma dos Impares(Si) : 1+7+5+1 = 14, e Soma dos Pares(Sp) : 7+1+6 = 14. Sendo Si - Sp = 0, logo, divisível por 11. Ou seja, eu preciso separar algarismo por algarismo, somar eles em par ou impar e depois subtrair, para ver se dão 0 ou são divisíveis por 11.

Comment: @PedroHenrique +1 pela tentativa, gostei particularmente pelo modo eficiente em que você usou array para os strings. Mas pelo que entendi, este modo não servirá, e mesmo sendo útil para outras circunstâncias, não será para o OP.

Comment: @Mondial, você tem algum exemplo de número que não funciona com esse método?

Comment: @PedroHenrique O número, por exemplo, 439087 não funciona, pois ele vai fazer a subtração colocando como par = 1 e par = 0 segundo o if, e colocar que dá para dividir por 11, sendo que não da. Eu preciso de uma maneira de separar cada algarismo e depois verificar se ele é par ou impar, para somente depois, subtrair e ver se é 0 ou um número divisível por 11.

Comment: Mas 439087 é divisível por 11.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Verifiquei o código, e funciona sim, +1. Acredito que isto deve bastar para o OP.

Comment: Hahaha, fiquei desesperado aqui! Qualquer dúvida ou problema, basta comentar! :)

Comment: @Nexus Tem necessidade mais não mano, o código deu certinho :) . Inclusive já te dei +100 de gratificação. Vlw mano pelo esforço e paciência comigo.